# Starting Scala application in SBT for integration test

Tags: scala, integration-testing, sbt, scalatra

I have a Scalatra web service that runs with embedded Jetty.  I'd now like to write integration tests that:

- start the service (using the main method of the application)
- run the tests (driving the HTTP interface)
- stop the service.

This should all be triggered by an SBT command.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write such integration tests on top of BDD test frameworks like Specs. [Unfiltered](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered) project has many such examples that should work for other web frameworks like Scalatra.

For example, take a look at [ServerSpec](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/9a4c3fba34a2d5321840b598dccd887d3f1e4bd0/filter/src/test/scala/ServerSpec.scala):

```
"A Server" should {
  "respond to requests" in {
    http(host as_str) must_== "test"
  }
  ....
}
```

It's starting up a test server specified in `setup` and hitting it using Dispatch in the specification. The key part is implemented in [`unfiltered.spec.jetty.Served` trait](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/master/spec/src/main/scala/jetty/Served.scala), which does that you described: starting and stopping the service. There's also Specs2 version: [`unfiltered.specs2.jetty.Served`](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/master/specs2/src/main/scala/jetty/Served.scala).

Another trick you could use is [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver), which my favorite plugin while doing any web development, especially used in conjunction with JRebel. This plugin can load your web server in the background. I haven't tried test together, but it could work if you don't have to change the server-side during the test.

Answer (score 1):

Scalatra offers a DSL to write tests. There is support for [specs2](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/testing/specs2.html) and [scalatest](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/testing/scalatest.html).

[By default](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/2.2.x_2.10/test/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/test/EmbeddedJettyContainer.scala) an embedded Jetty will be used for testing. If you want to provide your own server, you can reuse the `EmbeddedJettyContainer` implementation and override `start`, `stop` and `servletContextHandler`.

`start` will be called before executing the tests, which allows to start your server if required. `stop` is called after the tests. `servletContextHandler` is required in order to add your servlets using `addServlet(..)`.

This is from the spec2 integration:

```
trait BaseScalatraSpec extends SpecificationStructure with FragmentsBuilder with ScalatraTests {
  override def map(fs: =>Fragments) = Step(start()) ^ super.map(fs) ^ Step(stop())
}

trait ScalatraTests extends EmbeddedJettyContainer with HttpComponentsClient { }
```

Alternatively you can provide your own [Container](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/2.2.x_2.10/test/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/test/Container.scala) implementation.